# bug with exceptions in formular

Tags: php, html

here's my trouble: I have a html formula which work.

But... I'd like to create exceptions in case there's not many pictures to insert.

for this i put a `if(isset($_FILES)` around the code

With this the code are correctly inserted  but I have an error if file keeps empty:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /....

So i replace `$_FILES` by `$_POST` but on this case no files are updated (present or not).

So i put a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what happen and surprise !! no `$_POST['photo']` and no `$_POST['alt']` appears !!

Question  :

how can deal with the exception in case there's only one photo to record, without getting a copy error or bdr error?

Here are the codes:

```
<?php 
require_once("init.inc.php");
//--- ENREGISTREMENT PRODUIT ---//
if(!empty($_POST))
var_dump($_POST);
{
  if ( isset($_FILES['photo1']))
  {
    $photo_bdd = ""; 
    $photo_dossier = ""; 
    $v=1;
    $prepa_name1  = substr($_POST['titre'], 0, 45);  
    $name1= $prepa_name1 . $v . ".jpg" ;
    $photo_bdd1 = RACINE_SITE . "photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name1";
    $photo_dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . RACINE_SITE . "/photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name1"; 
    copy($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);
    $_FILES['photo1'] ="";
    $v++ ;
  }

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description1 = $_POST['description1'];
  $description1 = str_replace ( $character , $replace ,  $description1, )  ;
  //$character= "jusqu'a";
  //$replace = "jusqu\'a" ;
  //$description1 = $_POST['description1'];
  //$description1 = str_replace ( $character , $replace ,  $description1, )  ;
  echo $description1 ;

  if ( isset($_FILES['photo2']))
  {
    $photo_bdd = ""; 
    $photo_dossier = ""; 
    $prepa_name2  = substr($_POST['titre'], 0, 45);  
    $name2= $prepa_name2 . $v . ".jpg" ;
    $photo_bdd2 = RACINE_SITE . "photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name2";
    $photo_dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . RACINE_SITE . "/photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name2"; 
    copy($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);
    $v++ ;
  }

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description2 = $_POST['description2'];
  $description2 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $description2 )  ;
  //echo $description2 ;

  if ( isset($_FILES['photo3']))
  {
    $photo_bdd = ""; 
    $photo_dossier = ""; 
    $prepa_name3  = substr($_POST['titre'], 0, 45);  
    $name3= $prepa_name3 . $v . ".jpg" ;
    $photo_bdd3 = RACINE_SITE . "photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name3";
    $photo_dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . RACINE_SITE . "/photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name3"; 
    copy($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);
    $v++ ;
  }

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description3 = $_POST['description3'];
  $description3 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $description3, )  ;
  //echo $description3 ;

  if ( isset($_FILES['photo4']))
  {
    $photo_bdd = ""; 
    $photo_dossier = ""; 
    $prepa_name4  = substr($_POST['titre'], 0, 45);  
    $name4= $prepa_name4 . $v . ".jpg" ;
    $photo_bdd4 = RACINE_SITE . "photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name4";
    $photo_dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . RACINE_SITE . "/photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name4"; 
    copy($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);
    $v++ ;
  }

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description4 = $_POST['description4'];
  $description4 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $description4, )  ;
  //echo $description4 ;

  if ( isset($_FILES['photo5']))
  {
    $photo_bdd = ""; 
    $photo_dossier = ""; 
    $prepa_name5  = substr($_POST['titre'], 0, 45);  
    $name5= $prepa_name5 . $v. ".jpg" ;
    $photo_bdd5 = RACINE_SITE . "photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name5";
    $photo_dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . RACINE_SITE . "/photos/$_POST[categorie]/$name5"; 
    copy($_FILES['photo5']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);
    $v++ ;
  }

  $character= "'" ;
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description5 = $_POST['description5'];
  $description5 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $description5, )  ;
  //echo $description5 ;

  $character= "'" ;
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $description6 = $_POST['description6'];
  $description6 = str_replace ( $character , $replace ,  $description6, )  ;
  //echo $description6 ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail1 = $_POST['detail1'];
  $detail1 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail1, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail2 = $_POST['detail2'];
  $detail2 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail2, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail3 = $_POST['detail3'];
  $detail3 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail3, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail4 = $_POST['detail4'];
  $detail4 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail4, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail5 = $_POST['detail5'];
  $detail5 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail5, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail6 = $_POST['detail6'];
  $detail6 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail6, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail7 = $_POST['detail7'];
  $detail7 = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail7, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail_livraison = $_POST['detail_livraison'];
  $detail_livraison = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail_livraison, )  ;

  $character= "'";
  $replace = "\'" ;
  $detail_prix = $_POST['detail_prix'];
  $detail_prix = str_ireplace ( $character , $replace ,  $detail_prix, )  ;

  echo ' <br/>';
  $exec =executeRequete("INSERT INTO produit 
  (
    groupe,
    categorie,
    titre,
    description1,
    evaluation1,
    evaluation2,
    detail_livraison,
    detail1,
    detail2,
    detail3,
    detail4,
    detail5,
    detail6,
    detail7,
    stock,
    prix,
    detail_prix,
    photo1,
    alt1,
    photo2,
    alt2,
    photo3,
    alt3,
    photo4,
    alt4,
    photo5,
    alt5,
    description2,
    description3,
    description4,
    description5,
    description6,
    lien,
    magasin,
    divers
  )
  values 
  (
    '$_POST[groupe]',
    '$_POST[categorie]',
    '$_POST[titre]',
    '$description1',
    '$_POST[evaluation1]',
    '$_POST[evaluation2]',
    '$detail_livraison',
    '$detail1',
    '$detail2',
    '$detail3',
    '$detail4',
    '$detail5',
    '$detail6',
    '$detail7',    
    '$_POST[stock]',
    '$_POST[prix]',
    '$detail_prix',
    '$photo_bdd1',
    '$prepa_name1',
    '$photo_bdd2',
    '$prepa_name2',
    '$photo_bdd3',
    '$prepa_name3',
    '$photo_bdd4',
    '$prepa_name4',
    '$photo_bdd5',
    '$prepa_name5',
    '$description2',
    '$description3',
    '$description4',
    '$description5',
    '$description6',
    '$_POST[lien]',
    '$_POST[magasin]',
    '$_POST[divers]'
    )");
 
  $contenu .= '<div class="validation">Le produit a été ajouté</div>';
} 
?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'ajout'))
{
echo '
    <h1> Formulaire Produits </h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    
       <label for="groupe">groupe</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="groupe" name="groupe"  placeholder="Groupe"><br><br>
    
        <label for="categorie">categorie</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="categorie" name="categorie" placeholder="Categorie"><br><br>
        
        <label for="titre">titre</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="titre" name="titre"  placeholder="Titre"><br><br>
        
        <label for="description1">description1</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description1" name="description1" placeholder="Description1"><br><br>
         
          <label for="evaluation1">evaluation1</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="evaluation1" name="evaluation1" placeholder="Evaluation1"><br><br>
                
        <label for="evaluation2">evaluation2</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="evaluation2" name="evaluation2"  placeholder="Evaluation2"><br><br>
 
        <label for="detail_livraison">Detail_livraison</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail_livraison" name="detail_livraison" placeholder="Detail_livraison"><br><br>

        <label for="detail1">detail1</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail1" name="detail1" placeholder="detail1"><br><br>
        
        <label for="detail2">detail2</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail2" name="detail2" placeholder="detail2"><br><br>
        
        <label for="detail3">detail3</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail3" name="detail3" placeholder="detail3"><br><br>
        
         
        <label for="detail4">detail4</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail4" name="detail4" placeholder="detail4"><br><br>
        
          
        <label for="detail5">detail5</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail5" name="detail5" placeholder="detail5"><br><br>
        
         
        <label for="detail6">detail6</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail6" name="detail6" placeholder="detail6"><br><br>
        
         
        <label for="detail7">detail7</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail7" name="detail7" placeholder="detail7"><br><br>
           
        <label for="stock">stock</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="stock"><br><br>
              
        <label for="prix">prix</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="prix" name="prix" placeholder="prix"><br><br>
        
        <label for="detail_prix">detail_prix</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="detail_prix" name="detail_prix" placeholder="Detail_prix "><br><br>
 
        <label for="photo1">photo1</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1"><br><br>
        
         <label for="photo2">photo2</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="photo2" name="photo2"><br><br>
        
         <label for="photo3">photo3</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="photo3" name="photo3"><br><br>
        
         <label for="photo4">photo4</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="photo4" name="photo4"><br><br>
        
         <label for="photo5">photo5</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="photo5" name="photo5"><br><br>
        
        <label for="description2">description2</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description2" name="description2" placeholder="Description2"><br><br>
        
        <label for="description3">description3</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description3" name="description3" placeholder="Description3"><br><br>
         
        <label for="description4">description4</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description4" name="description4" placeholder="Description4"><br><br>
          
        <label for="description5">description5</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description5" name="description5" placeholder="Description5"><br><br>

        <label for="description6">description6</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="description6" name="description6" placeholder="Description6"><br><br>

        <label for="lien">lien</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lien" name="lien" placeholder="Lien du produit"><br><br>
        
        <label for="magasin">magasin</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="magasin" name="magasin" placeholder="Amazone"><br><br>
         
         <label for="divers">divers</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="divers" name="divers" placeholder="divers"><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="enregistrement du produit">
    </form>';
}
?>
```

`var_dump($_POST)` outputs:

```
array(25) { ["groupe"]=> string(6) "mlkmlk" ["categorie"]=> string(4) "test" ["titre"]=> string(4) "test" ["description1"]=> string(0) "" ["evaluation1"]=> string(0) "" ["evaluation2"]=> string(0) "" ["detail_livraison"]=> string(0) "" ["detail1"]=> string(0) "" ["detail2"]=> string(0) "" ["detail3"]=> string(0) "" ["detail4"]=> string(0) "" ["detail5"]=> string(0) "" ["detail6"]=> string(0) "" ["detail7"]=> string(0) "" ["stock"]=> string(0) "" ["prix"]=> string(0) "" ["detail_prix"]=> string(0) "" ["description2"]=> string(0) "" ["description3"]=> string(0) "" ["description4"]=> string(0) "" ["description5"]=> string(0) "" ["description6"]=> string(0) "" ["lien"]=> string(0) "" ["magasin"]=> string(0) "" ["divers"]=> string(0) "" }
```

You can see no photo and alt appears .

Comment: SO is an English site.

Comment: sorry i modify text

Comment: You must translate the title too, and format the code and data properly, and stick to one problem at a time, ensuring you've given us a [mre] of your issue. And make sure you tell us exactly where your error is. See [ask] and the [tour] for more info.

Comment: i think i can' do better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: i dont undestand where is the problem message and code are clean u block my need of help for details my employees wait for answer please be prount

Comment: can u unblock message please

Comment: It requires 3 votes to re-open it (just like 3 votes were required to close it). Be patient.

Comment: However: 1) `$_FILES` is the correct place to find uploaded files. You will never find them in `$_POST`. 2) Your code is unnecessarily repetitive. Learn how to loop through an array. You can just loop through `$_FILES` and process each photo you find, instead of repeating the same code 6 times.

Comment: 3) Which line of code causes the `Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty` error? It's not clear, and you have shown us a lot of code!

Comment: the line "copy($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'],$photo_dossier);" make the error when there is no files to upload ( here is my problem )

Comment: Even if you have the `isset` checking the `$_FILES`, it can still be that the file was not uploaded, if it fails the server's basic validation. I don't know for sure but that could be why you still have an issue. Make sure your code will check `$_FILES["photo1"]["error"]` (for example) to see if any error occurred in each upload, before trying to copy the file. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for more information and examples.

Comment: i think u dont undestand my trouble i dont want to dowload automaticy 5 photos sometimes it happen thers only one or two photos to download there appears the error i wnt to be able to record 1 2 3 4 or 5 photos without generating error